# Wildcard matching in a React if statement?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, wildcard

Is it possible to do a wildcard matching in a React if statement?
For example if my url contains either localhost or production, and I want to do the following:

```
  render() {
if (window.commonUI.hostname like '%local%') {
  return (
    // do something
  )
} else if (window.commonUI.hostname like '%prod%') {
    return (
      // do something else
    )
... and so on
```

Is this valid/ correct React syntax? I am getting an error when I compile my code and couldnt find any support for wildcards in React

Comment: `I am getting an error when I compile` ?

Comment: You can use something like this for condition `process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I guess my main question is, is wildcard checking allowed/ possible in React? Thanks

Comment: @prasanth Sorry the error I am getting is: `Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected )`

Answer (score 0):

**Wildcard matching in a React if statement?**

> Wildcard Method does't not support in react or Javascript.

Better you could use

1. **[regex.test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)**
2. [**string.indexOf**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
3. **[string.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)**

For your case simple validate with `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable

```
render() {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development') {
      return (
        // do something
      )
    } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
      return (
          // do something else
        )
        ....
    }
```